# How Oracle calculates the db block changes segment metric?

Tags: oracle, database-administration

This week I came across an interesting point. It was necessary to calculate in which segments of the database the greatest changes were occurring. I first accessed view `dba_hist_seg_stat`. However, I found incorrect data on metric `db block changes`, so I started an investigation. I found out that view `dba_hist_seg_stat` receives its data based on AWR snapshots from view `v$segstat`.

I started monitoring changes in the statistics of the `db block changes` metric on a test table. I created an empty table in a tablespace with an 8 KB block and a segment space management type of AUTO.

```
create table test.test2 ( id number);
```

after I started filling out the table

```
declare
 res_change number;
 res_block number;
 block_id_current_insert number;
begin
FOR cntr IN 1..7000
LOOP
 insert into test.test2 select dbms_random.value(1000000, 9999999) from dual;
 commit;
 select value into res_change from v$SEGSTAT seg where seg.ts#=6 and seg.obj#=1603792 and seg.dataobj#=1604115 and seg.statistic#=3;
 select count(distinct dbms_rowid.ROWID_BLOCK_NUMBER(rowid)) into res_block from test.test2;
 select dbms_rowid.ROWID_BLOCK_NUMBER(max(rowid)) into block_id_current_insert from test.test2;
 dbms_output.put_line('Count step - '||cntr||'.Db block changes - '|| res_change||'.Count block table test2 - '||res_block||'. Current block change - '||block_id_current_insert||'.');
end loop; 
end;
/
```

and got the following script output

```
Count step - 1.Db block changes - 240.Count block table test2 - 1. Current block change - 1054763.
Count step - 2.Db block changes - 240.Count block table test2 - 1. Current block change - 1054763.
Count step - 3.Db block changes - 240.Count block table test2 - 1. Current block change - 1054763.
.....
Count step - 6998.Db block changes - 528.Count block table test2 - 27. Current block change - 1054767.
Count step - 6999.Db block changes - 528.Count block table test2 - 27. Current block change - 1054767.
Count step - 7000.Db block changes - 528.Count block table test2 - 27. Current block change - 1054767.
PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

as it can be seen from the output, 7000 rows were inserted into the table. The number of existing blocks in the table became 27, and the number of changes in the table amounted to 528-240 = 288 blocks. Why? Moreover, as can be seen from the first 3 rows, the row was inserted into the table, but this did not cause an increase in the metric. Why?

Comment: Don't use `v$segstat` for this purpose. Instead, use `dba_tab_modifications`. The former is not well documented and folks can only make educated guesses how the internal instrumentation is operating. It's useful at a high level and for trending, but not for micro-accounting individual DMLs. Use the latter view for that.

Comment: About the only real useful purpose I've found for "`db block changes`" metric is to isolate a culprit in driving excessive dirtying of cache buffers that are causing DBWR to be excessively busy or falling behind. And that would be taken from `v$sesstat`, not from the `v$segstat`

Comment: I wanted to understand because I wanted to use the data in this view. however, this data will remain a mystery to all people....except Lawrence Ellison)

Comment: I've repeatedly given thought to the seg statistics data over the years, but I have yet to come up with a compelling use-case for the segment stat data. Session stats are much more helpful for most stats, and segment modifications much more useful for segment usage. Both of these however require writing your own capture tool that stores deltas over time, as AWR doesn't cover either in their hist tables.